# .Net 6 Middleware UrlRewrite Redirect from https to http

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I am trying to redirect a URL using Urlrewite middleware but the issue is it always redirected to HTTPS rather than HTTP even though I explicitly defined it to redirect to HTTP.

My application is using HTTPS but the script I am loading form using HTTP.

**My application URL is:**

> https://www.testlocal.com/

**While the URL of the application from where I am trying to load the script is:**

> http://www.localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js

Here is my code:

```
 var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirect("static/js/(.*)", "http://www.localhost:3000/static/js/$1");
        app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);
```

Redirection works good but the issue is it does not redirect to HTTP rather it redirects to HTTPS. Because that Script is not loaded.

Comment: Redirects like that are usually implemented at the top of the stack. In other words I'd configure the reverse proxy in front of kestrel to do the redirect.

Comment: Can explain how?

Comment: Depends on the proxy in use of course.

Comment: I try your code, But it Redirect to `http:xxxx` normally. You can remove `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` middleware and try again

Comment: It's not working for me. Because the other application is configured to use HTTPS only via IIS

Comment: sry, It works fine in my project. Maybe it related to your IIS?